# Issue with creating two Rectangle objects

Tags: java, object

I am trying to do my homework, and I have seem to be running into an error.  I have to build a rectangle and return the perimeter and area, with the rectangle default height and width being 1.  Everything looks good until I compile it, I am then told that the main method has to be static.  When I make the main method static, I then get the "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" error.  Any ideas on what I need to do to fix it?

```
package rectangle;
/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class Rectangle {
/** Main Method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create a rectangle with width and height
        SimpleRectangle rectangle1 = new SimpleRectangle();
        System.out.println("The width of rectangle 1 is " + 
                rectangle1.width + " and the height is " +
                rectangle1.height);
        System.out.println("The area of rectangle 1 is " +
                rectangle1.getArea() + " and the perimeter is " +
                rectangle1.getPerimeter());

        //Create a rectangle with width of 4 and height of 40
        SimpleRectangle rectangle2 = new SimpleRectangle(4, 40);
                System.out.println("The width of rectangle 2 is " + 
                rectangle2.width + " and the height is " +
                rectangle2.height);
                System.out.println("The area of rectangle 2 is " +
                        rectangle2.getArea() + " and the perimeter is "
                        + rectangle2.getPerimeter());



    }

        public class SimpleRectangle {
        double width;
        double height;

        SimpleRectangle() {
            width = 1;
            height = 1;
        }

        //Construct a rectangle with a specified width and height
        SimpleRectangle(double newWidth, double newHeight) {
            width = newWidth;   
            height = newHeight;
        }

        //Return the area of the rectangle
        double getArea() {
            return width * height;
        }
        //Return the perimeter of a rectangle
        double getPerimeter() {
            return (2 * width) * (2 * height);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please ensure that you include the *exact* error message that you get, i.e. cut and paste it into the question.

Comment: And please show by an obvious comment such as `// ****** error here ****` where the compiler error occurs.

Comment: Ummmm.. ahhhh.. ummmm... nevermind...stupid bracket....

Comment: I tried to compile your program, I didn't get any error. Can you please post stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create a class within a class, which is probably not what you want to do.

Either make `SimpleRectangle` a class in its own file, or just make `getPerimeter` and `getArea` methods on the `Rectangle` class and rename the `Rectangle` class to `SimpleRectangle` (you'll want to change your source file name accordingly)

Comment: That is exactly what it was.  I missed a bracket, once I put it in, the code compiled and did exactly what I wanted it to.  Thank you all.